# How to add a view above my NavigationControllers TableView

Tags: iphone

I have created a reusable class that fades in a "loading message" and indicator at the foot of the devices screen.

The problem I have is that when I'm adding the loadingview to a view that is contained in a NavigationController I want the view to stay at the bottom of the screen, even when scrolling the tableview.

How can i add a view ABOVE the TableView that is not affected by scrolling and such?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add it to the view containing the UITableView so that it is a peer to the UITableView rather than a child of it. Generally, this is the UIWindow that your application delegate owns.